# Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-appcenter-analytics': undefined

Tags: visual-studio-app-center-push

While Adding push plugin into cordova app I get the below error.

I have tried updating cordova and installing cocoapods, but still the same error.

**"framework" tag with type "podspec" is deprecated and will be removed. Please use the "podspec" tag.
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-appcenter-shared': undefined
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-appcenter-push': undefined**